# What can I do about the trash?

Tags: civil-law, tort, virginia

I live at the corner of a 4 way intersection.  There are houses on 3 corners, one being mine.  The 4th corner used to be an open field, owned by the 7/11 that was on the street behind me.  A few years ago, the 7/11 renovated to put in gas pumps and rebuilt the store further back.  While not parallel with me, its close enough now that it has become mildly annoying.  While not a lot, there is a steady stream of trash that now ends up in my front lawn, mostly being blown in by the wind.  Every day, there are plastic bags, lottery tickets, cups, cans, wrappers, etc on my lawn.  Needless to say, I dont like picking up other people's trash.  I have spoken to the owner's of the 7/11 about this a few times.  They are very friendly and apologetic.  I do find that after the few times I mention it, the trash in my lawn lessens.  I assume they instruct their employees to pick up the trash outside.  Of course, that reprieve is brief.  As I assume the employees stop caring and/or dont know due to the constant turnover.  Also, the owners arent often there.  Eventually, the stream of trash continues.  While the trash originates from 7/11, I am well aware that the majority of the problem isnt 7/11's employees, but the customers who go to 7/11.  They are the ones who litter.  I see people constantly throw trash anywhere but in the cans.  Sure, sometimes the cans are full, so people just lay their trash on top.

Like I said, I like the owners and have no desire to sour the relationship, not that there is any advantage to it.  However, I really am getting tired of the trash.  If it came to legal action, is 7/11 responsible for their customers' litter?  Any ideas, both legal or non?

This is in Virginia.

Comment: Virginia does have a litter control program that may have some use (although it seems mostly concerned with collecting a litter tax) It may not offer a way to force the business to pick up the trash, but maybe the DEQ would offer signage or trash receptacles that could help: https://lis.virginia.gov/cgi-bin/legp604.exe?181+ful+CHAP0615&181+ful+CHAP0615 Contact info: https://www.deq.virginia.gov/land-waste/litter-prevention A ‘$$$ fine for littering’ sign could prompt some people to look for the trash can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask the local government to enforce the littering ordinances against customers.

But, if the trash is put in trash cans and blows out, there is little that you can do legally.

In the law there are some bad things that happen for which someone is legally responsible due to their fault or circumstances, but there are many bad things that fall in the category of "shit happens" and for the most part, this is one of them.

Comment: If the trash cans are not regularly emptied by those who are supposed to, can't they be held responsible?

Comment: @Greendrake Conceivably, there could be a case for nuisance, but the damages would be low and you don't get you attorney fees if you prevail, and it wouldn't be easy to prove. Your money would be better spent on social media or pitching in to help clean up the mess.